# Issues creating transform mixin

Tags: css, sass, transform, mixins

I'm trying yo create a mixing for the CSS transform rule. I tried the following:

```
@mixin transform($action, $value) {
    -webkit-transform: $action($value);
    -ms-transform: $action($value);
    transform: $action($value);
}
```

ms for IE9
webkit for mobile devices
transform for the rest
[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

But I get this output:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate 45deg;
-ms-transform: rotate 45deg;
transform: rotate 45deg;
```

It seems the brackets `()` are not taken into account with this structure. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
@mixin transform($action) {
  -webkit-transform: $action;
  -ms-transform: $action;
  transform: $action;
}
```

And send in the parameter with ()

```
@include transform(rotate(45deg))
```

This will produce

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

**EDIT**

Solutions for keeping the two parameters

```
@mixin transform($action, $value) {
  -webkit-transform: $action + '(' + $value + ')';
  -ms-transform: $action + '(' +$value + ')';
  transform: $action + '(' + $value + ')';
}
```

or

```
@mixin transform($action, $value) {
  -webkit-transform: $action + '(#{$value})';
  -ms-transform: $action + '(#{$value})';
  transform: $action + '(#{$value})';
}
```

Comment: Well, it does work but I do not consider it a nice solution. I would like to know how you can create a mixing in the style I created it and specially why the brackets () are ignored in the output.

Comment: I do not know why the brackets () are ignored.. maybe it interpets it as a function? I added a edited solution to keep the two paramateres.. It's not very pretty, but it works

Comment: Indeed your first input was correct. It works fine. Thank you for both answers!